# How to set alpha value of navigation controller back button?

Tags: ios, swift

I just want to set the alpha of the back button arrow as I scroll my scroll view. To make it completely transparent, I've tried this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(alpha)
```

However, when `alpha` reaches 0, it just makes the colour of the back button white, rather than transparent. How can I fix this?

Comment: instead alpha 0.. try to hide the button `navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true`

Comment: @TonyMkenu No because it needs to fade as I scroll, rather than just going from visible to hidden

Comment: hide it only when alpha it is 0 - fade it when alpha is between1.. 0.1

Comment: Ah no that won’t work because setting the alpha doesn’t set the alpha of the button at all, just how much tint it has. So it never actually goes transparent. It’s just shades of white/tint colour.